# yum module not found in ansible but yum.py exists

Tags: ansible

I'm running a simple ansilbe playbook to launch an ec2 instance to do some stuff...the launch ec2 task works but yum does not...here is my `-vvv` output on that task

```
TASK [aws : install mdadm] *****************************************************
task path: /Users/usrxxx/Desktop/cloud-jumper/Ansible/roles/aws/tasks/main.yml:23
Using module file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/packaging/os/yum.py
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: usrxxx
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/cx/_fdv7nkn6dz21798p_bn9dp9ln9sqc/T/tmph8PxIS TO /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467/yum.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467/ /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467/yum.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/python /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467/yum.py; rm -rf "/Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485961836.82-278342855888467/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/cx/_fdv7nkn6dz21798p_bn9dp9ln9sqc/T/ansible_6aNOBu/ansible_module_yum.py", line 25, in <module>
    import yum
ImportError: No module named yum

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "yum"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/cx/_fdv7nkn6dz21798p_bn9dp9ln9sqc/T/ansible_6aNOBu/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 25, in <module>\n    import yum\nImportError: No module named yum\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

I looked in this path:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/packaging/os/
```

and it does contain yum.py....

my playbook looks like this as well:

```
--- # Launch ec2
- name: Create ec2 instance
  hosts: local2
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - aws
```

Comment: Trying to use `yum` on debian-family ec2 instance?

Comment: ah ok yeah! forgot I changed the ami...thanks!

Comment: wait...misspoke...I'm using a RHEL 7 ami...i'm running the playbook from my mac too

Comment: check for python `yum` package on **target** system

Comment: if I do a `pip list`, I see a `yum-metadata-parser (1.1.4)` package, not sure if thats the right one?....Also `yum` commands are working on the box normally when I ssh into it as well...

Answer (score 1):

This line gives me the impression that you are running ansible on a mac ...

```
  <localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/...
```

This line implies your task is running on the local machine instead of a remote host ...

```
   <localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: usrxxx
```

Your play or the task are running with a "local" connection, therefore implying you are trying to run yum on your mac. That is not likely to work, so check your host pattern, the connection method and the task invocation to make sure it runs on the remote host instead of on your mac.

Comment: Correct, there's `connection: local` in OP's playbook.